# .mouseup() only firing once

Tags: jquery, mouseup

I'm using jquery [.mouseup()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) to close a popop when a user clicks outside of it. My issue is this only works the first time it's used. I've tried the `.on()` version but that doesn't help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mouseup( function(e) {
      var container = $("#mpop-loop");
      if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.fadeOut("fast").remove();
      }
    });
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
      var container = $("#mpop-loop");
      if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.fadeOut("fast").remove();
      }
    });
});
```

How can I make this work everytime it's triggered?

Comment: Why not just bind the click event if you want it to trigger on click?

Comment: Once the container is faded out, how do you fade it back in?

Comment: @JamesAllardice Wouldn't that result in them only recognising clicks **inside** the popup, giving them the opposite functionality to what they want?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Yup, deleted comment. Missed the `=== 0` part (thought it was meant to run for clicks inside).

Comment: Is there any chance you could create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The popup is appended with ajax. I actually need to remove it each time too which I'll add to edit. So everytime the popup is shown it's being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.has` only works on descendants, ignoring the element itself. Try this (you don't need `$(document).ready` since you're binding the event to the document anyway):

```
    $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
      var container = $("#mpop-loop");
      if (!container.has(e.target).length && !container.is(e.target)) {
        container.fadeOut("fast");
      }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bWDXH/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function(){

    $("#mpop-loop").fadeOut("fast");

});
```

If you remove  "#mpop-loop" then the event  might have to be  added again when you open the container again.

Comment: The event is bound to the `<body>` tag, so you wouldn't need to rebind any of the event handlers (unless you removed/replaced the entire `<body>`). This doesn't provide the functionality they've described, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the delegation of the "on" function and use the ":not(.popup-class)" filter to delegate the click event to all elements on the page other than the popup? Just a thought so that the popup being clicked wont trigger a close as well.

Comment: like this? `$(document).on("click", ':not(#mpop-loop)', function () {`

Comment: yes though you'd need `'*:not(#mpop-loop)'` this uses the wildcard selector to match all